# Transitive Property in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a question that I feel I should know, but I've been having a hell of a time being as expressive as I would like to be in SQL.

My question is a simple one: what is an idiom for expressing transitive relationships in SQL?  A specific example:

Say I have the following schema:

```
user(email, name)
friends(friend1_email, friend2_email)
```

I'm having a problem expressing the following query:

Find users A, B, and C such that A is friends with B, B is friends with C, but C is not friends with A.

I will admit that this is homework, but I've been having conceptual issues with expressing queries.  Any assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to navigate a directional graph? If so, that's going to be really hard to do with pure SQL since that process is often deeply recursive.

Comment: @tadman: deeply recursive is not a problem with SQL as such, because recursive queries have been in the SQL standard for over a decade now. Only MySQL still can't do them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Granted the SQL *standard* allows for such things, but this is MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice with complex queries is always to start simple:

```
# Find friends A and B
select A.email as A_email, A.name as A_name, B.email as B_email, B.name as B_name
from user A
join friends
on A.email = friends.friend1_email
join user B
on B.email = friends.friend2.email
```

Simple enough, let's do it again for B and C:

```
# Find friends B and C
select B.email as B_email, B.name as B_name, C.email as C_email, C.name as C_name
from user B
join friends
on B.email = friends.friend1_email
join user C
on C.email = friends.friend2.email
```

Now, let's combine to get A, B, and C in a single query

```
# Find friends A, B, and C
select A.email as A_email, A.name as A_name, B.email as B_email, B.name as B_name, C.email as C_email, C.name as C_name
from user A
join friends f1
on A.email = f1.friend1_email
join user B
on f1.friend2_email = B.email
join friends f2
on B.email = f2.friend1_email
join user C
on f2.friend2_email = C.email
```

The above query will give us all users A who are friends with users B who are friends with users C, but does not limit the result set to those records where A and C are not friends. To get that result set we'll have to modify our query a bit.

```
# Find friends A, B, and C
select A.email as A_email, A.name as A_name, B.email as B_email, B.name as B_name, C.email as C_email, C.name as C_name
from user A
join friends f1
on A.email = f1.friend1_email
join user B
on f1.friend2_email = B.email
join friends f2
on B.email = f2.friend1_email
join user C
on f2.friend2_email = C.email
left join friends f3
on A.email = f3.friend1_email
and C.email = f3.friend2_email
where
    f3.friend1_email is null
```

Comment: Am I wrong in saying that this solutions wouldn't work if friendship wasn't symmetric?  That is, if user A was friends with B, but user B was not friends with A?

Comment: The solution I provided assumes that friendships are mutual and direction-less, such that A {is friends with} B implies that B { is friends with} A. If that is not the case then yes the query would have to be modified to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
select *
from friends a

--If this joins, a and b are friends
left join friends b
on (a.friend1_email = b.friend1_email or
    a.friend1_email = b.friend2_email or
    a.friend2_email = b.friend1_email or
    a.friend2_email = b.friend2_email)

--If this joins, b and c are friends
left join friends c
on (b.friend1_email = c.friend1_email or
    b.friend1_email = c.friend2_email or
    b.friend2_email = c.friend1_email or
    b.friend2_email = c.friend2_email)

--If this joins, c and a are friends.
--Also making sure that a is same person as a2
left join friends a2
on (c.friend1_email = a2.friend1_email or
    c.friend1_email = a2.friend2_email or
    c.friend2_email = a2.friend1_email or
    c.friend2_email = a2.friend2_email)
and (a.friend1_email = a2.friend1_email or
     a.friend1_email = a2.friend2_email or
     a.friend2_email = a2.friend1_email or
     a.friend2_email = a2.friend2_email)

where b.friend1_email is not null --join was made, a and b are friends
and c.friend1_email is not null --join was made, b and c are friends
and a2.friend1_email is null --join was NOT made, a and c are NOT friends
```